# While using MSAL-Angular and requesting an access_token for Azure Active Directory graph api, it gives token with aud of Microsoft graph api

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

While using MSAL-Angular and requesting an access_token for Azure Active Directory graph api(https://graph.windows.net/), it gives token with aud of Microsoft graph api(https://graph.microsoft.com)

i need to call azure active directory graph api because Microsoft graph api is in beta version. now when i use msalService to get access_token for Azure Active Directory graph api it gives token with aud of microsoft graph api. when i tried to use that token it gives error of 'Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request.' even though token is with valid time.

I am using below typescript code to generate the access_token
 public async getAccessToken(endpointUri: string): Promise {

```
this.accessToken = '';
const scopes = this.msalService.getScopesForEndpoint(endpointUri);

return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
  this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent(scopes)

    .then(accessToken => {
      this.accessToken = accessToken;
      resolve(true);
      // tslint:disable-next-line: promise-function-async
    }).catch(() => {

      return this.msalService.acquireTokenPopup(scopes)
        .then(token => {

          this.accessToken = token;
          resolve(true);

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(new Error(error));
        });
    });
});
```

}